# how can I create a flow chart like this in Latex

Tags: diagrams, overleaf

I want to create a flow chart like the following attached one including images inside. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! What you try so far? Where you stuck in your efforts?  Which package you like to use for drawing?

Comment: Questions that receive help on this site are mostly about one concrete issue in a small example document code. To start, please search for tree+forest, or tree+tikz on this site, there are tons of flow chart examples. Take that most similar to your goal,  and try to adapt to your own needs. If you stuck on some point, post a minimal example code and the screenshot of the output,  and explain clearly the issue with that example.

Comment: Great!
Thank you for your help. @Fran